# Is there a way to run helgrind/drd in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, linker, valgrind

I try to figure out some problem caused by thread sync in mips android, I installed valgrind in my mips machine, It is ok when using memcheck, but when I changed the option to --tool=helgrind,  logcat says this:

```
I/start_valgrind.sh( 9328): link_image[2207]:  9329 could not load needed library '/data/local/Inst/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_drd-mips32-linux.so' for '/system/bin/app_process' (mips_relocate_got[1749]:  9329 cannot locate 'sched_yield'...
```

I located sched_yield in /system/lib/libc.so, but I can't find a way to add it to the link path; I using valgrind-3.10.0 and my android system version is 4.1.

So is it possible to run helgrind/drd in android? Thanks!